# A man wants to create a bomb shelter in a small cave on his land, but there's no visible water source, except a dripping wall. What to do?

Tags: water, caves

A man who wants to live in a hidden cave on his mountain property in the Pyrenees has hired a caver to evaluate the cave as a bomb shelter in case of a nuclear war. The cave is small compared to most caves but he used to sleep in it when he was a boy with his two brothers. The cave is dry and has 2 caverns. In the first cavern, there is a fire pit. The smoke goes up into a makeshift smoke stack.  In the back cavern, one wall is slightly dripping water. The opposite wall is cold to the touch. He is looking for a source of water but can't find a stream. No one knows how deep the cave extends behind the wall.

Comment: Dripping water to where? Usually a pool will form

Comment: If this is to ride out nuclear war, you don't want to use *any* external source of water - it should be considered irradiated. The fact that potentially radioactive water is seeping into your fallout shelter is actually a big problem, not a benefit. A bomb shelter's food and water should be stored beforehand, not brought in from the outside after the fact.

Comment: I don't now much about nuclear sheltering, but what @NuclearHoagie writes about water also would apply to food, and fuel (since you talk about a smoke stack). Everything will need to be stored. Is that cave big enough? Also, will outside air be breathable? (I have no idea myself.)

Comment: Susan, that sounds interesting but if you first dropped every reference to anything but the need for a water source in general, and the slightly dripping water in particular, what would be lost?

Comment: @NuclearHoagie : in such cases long-term survival won't be guaranteed no matter what you can do with private means with a cave. Your chances will still be at least somewhat higher compared to those who stay outside.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Water doesn't turn radioactive when it's irradiated; what you worry about is that the water picks up radioactive particles that you then ingest. Filtering the water through many meters of dirt seems like a pretty efficient way to purify it. I'd be more worried about radioactive fallout entering through the described chimney.

Comment: If filtering doesn't do, then distillation should remove everything else except for tritium. Stills are cheap, low-tech. Resonably easy to build and maintain. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_still

Answer (score 14):

**Carve out a bowl**

The guy carves out a bowl depression below the drip so the water collects in it.

One drop every six seconds is about three litres per day which is enough to survive on.

Comment: How cool! I like this idea. So having a way to purify the water will be important and doable.

Comment: @SusanEtchey depending on the source of the water, purification or sterilization may be completely unnecessary. Mountain springs are unlikely to be contaminated.

Comment: Just like all the cliff communities at Mesa Verde.

Comment: @SusanEtchey Water purification will be fairly simple. 1) subterranean water is usually very pure to start with 2) most nuclear fallout will be captured to the top soil 3) a sand and coal bed will take care of preactically everything else 4) your protagonist can use prophylactics against for instance Iodine 131 contamination. 5) boiling will sterilise the water. By this point, whatever little contaminants remain, such as Cs-137, can probably be tolerated, being too low dose to be of any concern, and biological halflife is rather brief anyway.

Comment: This was actually done in the Predjama Castle. The castle is built into a cave and a series of channels were carved into the walls to direct the water into a cistern.

Comment: One drop per six seconds is 10 * 60 * 24 = 14400 drops per day. A [drop of water is about 50 µl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop_(unit)), so that is 14400 * .05 = 720ml ≈ 0.7L per day.

Answer (score 12):

Assuming this water will be free from contamination and radiation then it should have already carved itself a reservoir of some sort under the drip. If not then channel the drip into a pool or containers for your water supply.

Since time is not an issue here, I'd take some samples to water testing labs and get them checked out for consumption. Most water bottling businesses can assist with this, or university labs. Alternatively you can obtain your own water purification infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you for a practical solution.